# Python's string.strip() weird behavior

Tags: python, string, strip

I got a string looking like that:

```
EVENTS: RAID
Volume Set Information 
Volume Set Name : ARC-1120-VOL#00 
Raid Set Name   : Raid Set # 00   
Volume Capacity : 1.0GB
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun  : 00/00/00
Raid Level      : Raid5
Stripe Size     : 64K
Member Disks    : 3
Cache Mode      : Write Back
Tagged Queuing  : Enabled
Volume State    : Degraded

Volume Set Information 
Volume Set Name : ARC-1120-VOL#01 
Raid Set Name   : Raid Set # 00   
Volume Capacity : 5.0GB
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun  : 00/00/01
Raid Level      : Raid5
Stripe Size     : 64K
Member Disks    : 3
Cache Mode      : Write Back
Tagged Queuing  : Enabled
Volume State    : Degraded
```

And when I done a string.strip("EVENTS: RAID\n"), i got this result:

```
olume Set Information 
Volume Set Name : ARC-1120-VOL#00 
Raid Set Name   : Raid Set # 00   
Volume Capacity : 1.0GB
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun  : 00/00/00
Raid Level      : Raid5
Stripe Size     : 64K
Member Disks    : 3
Cache Mode      : Write Back
Tagged Queuing  : Enabled
Volume State    : Degraded

Volume Set Information 
Volume Set Name : ARC-1120-VOL#01 
Raid Set Name   : Raid Set # 00   
Volume Capacity : 5.0GB
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun  : 00/00/01
Raid Level      : Raid5
Stripe Size     : 64K
Member Disks    : 3
Cache Mode      : Write Back
Tagged Queuing  : Enabled
Volume State    : Degraded
```

Question: Why the V of "Volume Set Information" is disappeared ?

As you can see, I want to remove the first line, if anybody know a better way to do? (I know there is a lot of "pythonic" guys here... give me your best shot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read [the documentation of `strip()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-string.html#l2h-817)?

It strips of any number of characters that you provided, so `.strip("EVENTS: RAID\n")` strips of every `E`, every `V`, every `E`, every `N`, ... until one character is found that's not in there! This is why the `V` of `Volume Set Information` goes missing.

Try `replace(string, "EVENTS: RAID\n", "", 1)` instead.

Comment: okay thanks. I was thinking that it remove all the V of Volume but I misunderstand the doc.

Answer (score 3):

Because the argument of `strip` is the string of characters to remove and yours includes "V".

Why are you passing it that string anyways?

Answer (score 1):

`string.strip()` removes all instances of the given characters from the string's beginning or end.

Try something along the lines of

```
linebreak_pos = string.find("\n")
if linebreak_pos != -1:
    string = string[linebreak_pos:]
```

or if you want something quick and dirty,

```
string = "\n".join(string.split("\n")[1:])
```

Comment: Strip only removes *that* V because it only removes leading and trailing characters - not characters that are in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`Strip()` will strip all the leading characters that match one of the characters you specified in its parameter string. Since 'V' is one of them (in EVENTS), it gets stripped.

What you want to do is to replace the leading "EVENTS: RAID\n". You can use regular expressions for that.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is absolutely correct.

strip(chars) is supposed to chop of all trailing/leading characters as specified in 'chars'.
It is not about performing a string.replace() operation. Since 'V' is specificed in 'chars' you will lose the first 'V' as well. Please check back with the string.strip() documentation if you don't believe it.